# Play Framework 2.4 application always creating a 1.sql evolution even when turn off

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-evolutions

I'm in the process of converting a Play Framework application from version 2.3.X to 2.4.X.

Everything is working except for one thing. A file is created each time I launch the server.

The file is `/conf/evolutions/default/1.sql`

**The strange this is that I don't use evolutions**. I still keep the `evolutions` folder to keep track of my sql conversion files (that I code myself).

In my application.conf file, this is what I have related to evolutions. I know they both do the same things but even with both of these lines, the problem still happen.

```
play.evolutions.enabled=false

play.evolutions {
  db.default.enabled = false
}
```

Is there a setting somewhere to prevent this? I didn't have this problem in version 2.3.X.

Thanks

Comment: Have you used `play.evolutions.enabled=false`?

Comment: I've edited my answer with the content of my application.conf file related to evolutions

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this? I am experiencing the same problem. I have play.evolutions.enabled=false in the config and I do not have the evolutions dependency in build.sbt

Answer (score 3):

You can try adding

```
play.modules.disabled += "play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsModule"
```

to your application.conf that did the trick for me.

Comment: will try that really soon and let you know